# Test Trend Result and Test Trend Result(Advanced) widgets no longer available on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, widget

Test Trend Result and Test Trend Result(Advanced) widgets no longer available on Azure Devops. Few years back as well we had this issue and I am facing this issue again.
Anyone aware on any ongoing issue?
[Azure widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoSxT.png)

1. Navigated to Azure Devops dashboard
2. Tried to add Test Trend Result widget